# Select a list of joined objects, and their related entities

Tags: entity-framework

I have three tables:

QuestionWrappers
Questions
Options

What I want is a list of Questions with the Options collection bound to each one.

Here's what I'm trying so far:

```
return context.QuestionWrappers
                    .Include("Question")
                    .Include("Question.Options")
                    .Select(q => q.Question)
                    .ToList();
```

Unfortunately, this returns a list of "Question" objects, but missing the Question.Options.

Comment: strange. If there's actual data in the Options table, and the Navigation property is actually called `Options`, this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you almost had it, and this will work:

```
return context.QuestionWrappers
                .Include(qw=>qw.Question.Select(q=>q.Options))
                .ToList();
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx